# Install Spark and Hadoop in the same machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm trying to install Spark Apache and Hadoop in the same machine. Spark will be used to process data, and HDFS from Hadoop will be used to store data. I first started by installing spark and it worked perfectly. But, when I started installing Hadoop and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable HDFS worked, but spark break down and shows: `Files was unexpected at this time.` when I launched it. When I deleted JAVA_HOME, Spark worked again but it's not the case for HDFS. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using?  Can you show your JAVA_HOME path? Your JAVA_HOME path should not contain spaces.

Comment: I'm working on windows 10 and my JAVA_HOME is : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"

Comment: I see at least 2 spaces in your path - "Program Files (x86)". Try to use different path for JAVA_HOME - without spaces.

Comment: install java again or just move the files in another directory?

Comment: I fixed it, I just moved the java folder in program files to a directory where there is no spaces and it works. Now, I have spark and hadoop both installed in my computer.